# Stripping unwanted chars from a string in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some code below which returns a clean string

How would retain commas in the output

```
select @cleanline=line from #tbl

    While PatIndex('%[^A-Z,a-z,0-9]%', @cleanline) > 0         
    Set @cleanline = Stuff(@cleanline, PatIndex('%[^A-Z,a-z,0-9]%', @cleanline), 1, '') 

    print @cleanline
```

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Your code **does** retain commas. Are you asking how not to?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didnt make myself clear - I need to keep a-z 0-9 and commas

Comment: @Rob - Well If I try `declare @cleanline varchar(max) = 'one,two,three,$'` and run it through your code the commas are retained.

Comment: @Martin How strange on my version of SQL server they are stripped...

Comment: @Martin Collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , Server = Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86)   May 26 2009 14:24:20   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: @Rob: do you have a sample string please too?

Comment: @gbn - you are a star - want to know why - because dozy bugger that I am have mixed up my files - the file imusing is a tab file (hence no commas!!!) omg i feel stupid now.

Comment: @gbn, @Martin how would I retain a tab is it \t?

Comment: No. `'%[^A-z0-9' + CHAR(9) + ']%'`

Comment: Either char(9) or copy a tab in from notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Change `%[^A-Z,a-z,0-9]%` to `%[^A-Z0-9]%` or`%[^A-Za-z0-9]%`</strike>

By default, SQL Server isn't case sensitive and you don't need commas in [pattern-match strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Edit: turns out there are *no* commas in the data...

```
select @cleanline = line from #tbl
set @tokeeppattern = '%[^A-Z,a-z0-9' + CHAR(9) + ']%'


While PatIndex(@tokeeppattern, @cleanline) > 0         
Set @cleanline = Stuff(@cleanline, PatIndex(@tokeeppattern, @cleanline), 1, '') 

print @cleanline
```